# Error locating String field in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to find a company by its CNPJ(Brazilian corporate tax payer registry number) in a DB (H2), but it's returning an error

```
{
 "timestamp": "2022-03-30T19:30:23.823+00:00",
 "status": 404,
 "error": "Not Found",
 "path": "/companies/cnpj/30101554000146"
}
```

I've tried other alternatives using:

http://localhost:8080/companies/cnpj/'30.101.554/0001-46', http://localhost:8080/companies/cnpj/"30.101.554/0001-46",

but the error persists.  I implemented like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
 public class Company implements Serializable {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;

 private String name;
 @CNPJ
 private String cnpj;

//skipped
}

public interface CompanyRepository extends JpaRepository<Company,Long> {

 Optional<Company> findByCnpj(String cnpj);
}

public class CompanyDTO {
 private Long id;

 private String name;

 private String cnpj;

//skipped
}

@Service
@Transactionalpublic class CompanyService {

 @Autowired
 private CompanyRepository companyRepository;

 @Transactional(readOnly = true)
 public CompanyDTO findById(Long id) {
    Company resultado = companyRepository.findById(id).get();
    CompanyDTO dto = new CompanyDTO(resultado);
    return dto;
 }  

 @Transactional(readOnly = true)
 public CompanyDTO findByCnpj(String cnpf) {
    Optional<Company> resultado = companyRepository.findByCnpj(cnpf);
    CompanyDTO dto = new CompanyDTO(resultado.get());
    return dto;
    
 }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/companies")public class CompanyController {

 @Autowired
 private CompanyService companyService;


 @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
 public CompanyDTO findById(@PathVariable Long id) {
    return companyService.findById(id);
 }

 @GetMapping(value = "/cnpj/{cnpj}")
 public CompanyDTO findByCnpj(@PathVariable String cnpj) {
    return companyService.findByCnpj(cnpj);
 }
}
```

The expected output would be:

```
[
  {"id": 1,
   "nome": "Company 123",
   "cnpj": "30.101.554/0001-46"
  }
]
```

**UPDATE:**

I changed @GetMapping(value = "/cnpj/{cnpj}") to @GetMapping(value = "/cnpj/**") and:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/cnpj/**")
     public CompanyDTO findByCnpj(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return companyService.findByCnpj(request.getRequestURI().split(request.getContextPath() + "/cnpj/")[1]);
     }
```

Works for me! Thanks

Comment: To my eyes you didn’t encode the slash in your url correctly. Replace / with %2F in your cnpj

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't quite understand what correction I need to make.

Do I need to save the cnpj by replacing / to %2f or is it when I do the get?

Comment: When you get existing cnpj with slash, you need to use correct cnpj in your request. I can see you tried removing the slash and putting cnpj in quotes, which are incorrect ways to deal with slash. Slash is a special character, if it is a part of cnpj it needs to be encoded.

Comment: I still don't quite understand how to code. I tried changing the insert in the cnpj database to `30.101.554%2F0001-46` and I tried in the GET to `http://localhost:8080/fornecedores/cnpj/30.101.554%2F0001-46`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-slash-character-in-url), `pathParams` with slashes can be realy tricky while using spring-boot. This article explains pretty well what to do to avoid getting an `error 404` when your `pathVariable` has a slash.